# On the correctness of the padding example of RFC 5246

Tags: tls, padding

The PKCS#7 padding is defined in [rfc5652#section-6.3](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc5652#section-6.3)

> Some content-encryption algorithms assume the input length is a
> multiple of k octets, where k is greater than one.  For such
> algorithms, the input shall be padded at the trailing end with
> k-(lth mod k) octets all having value k-(lth mod k), where lth is
> the length of the input.  In other words, the input is padded at
> the trailing end with one of the following strings:
>
> ```
>                01 -- if lth mod k = k-1
>             02 02 -- if lth mod k = k-2
>                  .
>                  .
>                  .
>        k k ... k k -- if lth mod k = 0
> ```

As we can see, the padding bytes can contain a series of`01,02,...,`or,`16` for a 16-byte sized block cipher. While reading

- 2019 [Scalable Scanning and Automatic Classification of TLS Padding Oracle Vulnerabilities](https://www.usenix.org/system/files/sec19-merget.pdf) by Merget et al.

I've seen that they gave an example as;

> The second block contains the remaining 9 HMAC bytes and `7` bytes of padding `0x06`, see Figure 1. Note that the encryptor can also choose longer padding and append 23, 39, ...or 247 padding bytes (while setting the value of the padding bytes accordingly).

This is not PKCS#7 padding. So, I've looked at TLS 1.2's [RFC 5246](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc5246/#section-6.2.3.2) and see almost the same pattern;

> If the padding length were the minimum necessary, 6, the padding would be 6
> bytes, each containing the value 6.  Thus, the last 8 octets of the
> GenericBlockCipher before block encryption would be xx 06 06 06 06 06
> 06 06, where xx is the last octet of the MAC.

To be compatible with PKCS#7 padding, the above should be ( couldn't see an [errata](https://www.rfc-editor.org/errata_search.php?rfc=5246&rec_status=0))

> If the padding length were the minimum necessary, 7, the padding would be 7
> bytes, each containing the value 7.  Thus, the last 8 octets of the
> GenericBlockCipher before block encryption would be xx 07 07 07 07 07
> 07 07, where xx is the last octet of the MAC.

and the article has a mistake there, too.

As far as I know, these two resources are incorrect. Is there something that I've missed about the different designs/usages of PKCS#7 padding rules?

Comment: Note that I'm not considering SSLv3 padding where the last byte denotes the number of padding bytes and the rest of the padding can take any value.

Comment: Crossdupe https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/161153/rfc-5246-tls-1-2-padding-example-mistake and https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/88839/pkcs7-vs-tls-1-2-padding

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The padding used for CBC cipher suites in SSLv3 through TLS 1.2 is not PKCS#5/PKCS#7 padding. It's the padding used in SSL/TLS, which I haven't seen anywhere else.

The padding in [TLS 1.0](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc5246/#section-6.2.3.2), [TLS 1.1](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc4346#section-6.2.3.2) and [TLS 1.2](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc5246/#section-6.2.3.2) can be from 1 to 256 bytes, so it can fill multiple blocks. In the predecessor protocol [SSL 3.0](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc6101#section-5.2.3.2), it must complete exactly one block. In all versions, the last byte must be the length of the padding, excluding that last byte. The preceding bytes can take any value in SSL 3.0, and must be the padding length in TLS 1.0 through 1.2. For a block cipher with $B$-byte blocks:

| Specification | Total length | Blocks | Content |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| PKCS#7 | $n \in [1, B]$ bytes | $1$ | $(n, \ldots, n)$ |
| SSL 3.0 | $n \in [1, B]$ bytes | $1$ | $(?, \ldots, ?, (n-1))$ |
| TLS 1.0–1.2 | $n \in [1, 256]$ bytes | $1$ to $\lceil 256/B \rceil$ | $((n-1), \ldots, (n-1))$ |

As you can see, PKCS#7 fills the padding with the total padding length, whereas TLS 1.0–1.2 fills the padding with the total padding length minus one. The reason for this seemingly odd choice is that it's an adaptation of the SSL 3.0 padding, in which the last byte is a length byte which is not including in what the SSL specification calls the “padding”, and the “padding” proper can have arbitrary content.

The examples you cite from RFC 5246 and from Merget et al. are correct. If adding 7 bytes brings the plaintext to a multiple of the block size, then `06 06 06 06 06 06 06` is a possible TLS padding (as are `16 16 16 16 16 16 16 16 16 16 16 16 16 16 16 16 16 16 16 16 16 16 16`, etc.).